# What is the meaning of the notation [A|B] in Linear Algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I am going through Linear Algebra right now, we are using the book Elementary Linear Algebra by Andrilli. In one of the theorems he uses this notation without really introducing it. Here is the theorem:

Theorem 2.3 Let **AX**=**B** be a system of linear equations. If [**C**|**D**] is row equivalent to [**A**|**B**], then the system **CX**=**D** is equivalent to **AX**=**B**.

I just don't know how to read the [C|D] notation there. I want to say C divides D because that's the symbol for integer division, but I know that's not right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Let **AX**=**B** be a system of linear equations. If [**C**|**D**] is
>   row equivalent to [**A**|**B**], then the system **CX**=**D** is
>   equivalent to **AX**=**B**.

$[A\mid B]$ is just a $1\times 2$ matrix consisting of two [matrix blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix) $A$ and $B$ as first and second column entry.

So $\mid$ acts as layout separator not as division operator.

You could express the same as

> .. If $C$ is row equivalent to $A$ and $D$ is row equivalent to $B$, then
>   ..

but the aggregation via blocks allows more compact
statements.

Example:
$$
A X = B
$$
with
$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
X =
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} & x_{12} \\
x_{21} & x_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
B =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
4 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
then
$$
[A \mid B] =
\left[
\begin{array}{rr|rr}
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
3 & 4 & 4 & -1
\end{array}
\right]
$$
where I added the vertical line just for visual separation.

Comment: Ok. I almost understand are AX=B and [A|B] saying the same thing?

Comment: ok. I see. So just one more question, does it imply that [C|D] and [A|B] are equivalency classes of which some collection of matrices belong to?

Comment: Reading it a second time. $[A|B]$ can be used as a compact notation for the system $AX=B$, you find this as augmented matrices in Gauss elimination. $[A|B]$ just designates a matrix consisting of two submatrices $A$ and $B$.

Comment: In $[A,|B]$ one means a matrix $[ ]$ with two entries $[.|.]$ and we name the first one $A$ and the second $B$ and the big letters and the context indicate these are each matrices themselves. You should read about blockmatrices in a linear algebra text to get familliar. It is just grouping, making use of the fact that a submatrix can be treated as a number (a matrix is a ring element)   themselves which is good enough for matrix multiplication of the aggregate.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that, I think I understand what you are saying. A and B are each matrices that themselves make up a matrix. I'll look into what the blockmatrices are. The Wikipedia article makes me think that it's useful.

Comment: @JosiahBlaisdell By way of example: If $\mathbf A=\begin{bmatrix} a & c \\ b & d\end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathbf B =\begin{bmatrix} e\\ f\end{bmatrix}$, then we define their aggregate as $\mathbf {[A\mid B]} \mathop{:=} \left[\begin{array}{cc:c} a & c & e \\ b & d & f\end{array}\right]$.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, the $[\mathbf{A}|\mathbf{B}]$ notation signifies an "augmented matrix" associated with a system of linear equations. Your textbook probably has a definition of "augmented matrix". Try looking up this term in the index.

The concept is simple enough: $[\mathbf{A}|\mathbf{B}]$ is just the matrix $\mathbf{A}$, but with the vector $\mathbf{B}$ glued on as an extra column on the right. So, if $\mathbf{A}$ has $n$ columns, then $[\mathbf{A}|\mathbf{B}]$ will have $n+1$ columns.

More generally, $[\mathbf{A}|\mathbf{B}]$ denotes the matrix formed by gluing together two matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$.

Comment: oh. yes. in fact, on the page where he defines what an augmented matrix is he also introduces this notation. thanks!